# Change tab or open CSS file on SCSS build in Sublime Text 2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, python, shortcuts, ide, sublime-text-2

I use [SASS Package](https://github.com/WhatWeDo/Sublime-Text-2-SASS-Package) and [SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) on a regular basis in my development process through Sublime Text 2. The functionality of these are both great, but I'm hoping to reduce the number of steps it takes me to accomplish getting the files to the server.

My steps are as follows:

1. Write some SCSS in a file, for example `style.scss`.
2. Hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (build function) key binding to build the standard
   CSS file which is automatically generated with the same name as the
   SCSS file but with a `.css` prefix.  Example: `style.css`.
3. I then must either open the `style.css` file, or change to the tab
   for the file if it is already open.
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> `->` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> which is the key combo to sync
   the file to the server using the SFTP plugin.
5. Go back to the `.scss` file to start the process again.

Not too big of a deal. But when I'm doing it 600 times a day it becomes a little time consuming.

So I'm wondering if there is anyway through a plugin, python script, or other method to shorten this process.

---

My initial thoughts would be to have this function by either opening up the generated CSS file, or if it is already open, switch to the CSS file when I complete the build in step 2. 
(Note: This file will *always* have the same name and be in the same directory as the SCSS file).

And then hopefully have the reverse effect when I do the file sync in step 4.

It would be even better if I could just have it all happen at once when I build the SCSS file in step 2:

```
Build > Open CSS file > Sync CSS file > Close CSS file > Jump back to SCSS file
```

Any thoughts and suggestions are welcome, just trying to save some time and hand cramps.